# Is it possible to have a div fade out, then fade in at different position when page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Is it possible to have a (first)div fade out, then fade in at the different place(second div) and (second)div should be fade in at the (first)div position

It'd obviously use the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() functions but I'm not sure how divs fade in and fade out at the same time....
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").fadeOut(300,function(){ //hide first div
  $("#div2").fadeIn(); //show second div when first div is fully hidden.
})
```

You can use callback of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#div1").fadeOut()
   $("#div2").fadeIn()
```

as you want to **fade** them at same time, call **both functions at the same time.**

Answer (score 0):

Some of the previous answers will show the new div once the old has faded out. It sounds like you want the fading to happen at the same time. A solution to this would be to make sure div2 is positioned absolutely in the same place as div1 but with a lower z index so div1 completely overlays and hides it . Then as you fade out div1, div2 will fade in behind it.